# Is there a way to show the "clicks" in Android Espresso UI testing?

Tags: android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

We use Firebase Test Lab for our automated end to end testing, its been requested that we show the "clicks" so someone can follow along, being that all animations are disabled during a UI test is it possible to setup Espresso or Firebase to show the clicks as the test runner executes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-
In Developer Options > Enable Show touches
Hopefully that may do the trick for you :)
[image]

Comment: That wont really work in firebase test lab where we run our tests, google controls all aspects of the devices.

Comment: @bhawkins did you ever figure this out? Running into an issue where having the tap be visible in Firebase test labs would significantly help debug the issue.

Comment: You can do this via adb command as well-
adb shell settings put system show_touches 1